# Convert Persian (Jalali) calendar to timestamp on form field entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, confluence, jalali-calendar

I made a form with Confiforms in Confluence including a Persian calendar field. There is a Filter Control macro to filter the records. But this filter doesn't work fine with Persian dates. Because Persian dates are saved as timestamp but the Persian calendar field displays the date, not the timestamp, and when I want to filter records, I should write timestamp in the Persian calendar field to make filter work.

[Form ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgVHl.png)

The problem is I want that when I choose a date, it returned its timestamp to the field instead of date. (See the picture)

Is there any JavaScript/jQuery code to convert a Persian date entry of a field to timestamp?

Edit:
The shamsi date format of field entry is d-m-yy (eg. 15-12-1400)

Comment: Timestamps are always in Gregorian calendar dates, unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe you can convert a Jalali Date to a Gregorian Date and then convert that to a TimeStamp. I can post a short Javascript function to convert Jalali Dates to Gregorian Dates without the use of external libraries if that will answer your question or help you.

Comment: Here is my method to convert Persian Dates to any other calendars without external libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71421825/how-to-convert-persian-jalali-dates-to-other-18-calendar-dates-in-javascript-w/71421832#71421832

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following function will convert a Persian (Jalali) Date to a Timestamp (UTC based).

You pass the Jalali's year, month, and day to the function and the output is the timestamp in the UTC zone.

```js
function jalaliToUTCTimeStamp(year, month, day) {
const format=new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-u-ca-persian',{dateStyle:'short',timeZone:"UTC"});
let g=new Date(Date.UTC(2000,month,day));
    g=new Date(g.setUTCDate(g.getUTCDate()+226867));
const gY=g.getUTCFullYear(g)-2000+year;
    g=new Date(((gY<0)?"-":"+")+("00000"+Math.abs(gY)).slice(-6)+"-"+("0"+(g.getUTCMonth(g)+1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0"+(g.getUTCDate(g))).slice(-2));
let [pM,pD,pY] = [...format.format(g).split("/")],i=0;
    g=new Date(g.setUTCDate(g.getUTCDate()+~~(year*365.25+month*30.44+day-(pY.split(" ")[0]*365.25+pM*30.44+pD*1))-2));
while (i<4){
[pM,pD,pY]=[...format.format(g).split("/")];
if(pD==day && pM==month && pY.split(" ")[0]==year)return +g;
g=new Date(g.setUTCDate(g.getUTCDate()+1)); i++;
}
throw new Error('Invalid Persian Date!');
}
//==========================================================
// Test Units
//==========================================================
console.log(jalaliToUTCTimeStamp(1400,12,5));
console.log(jalaliToUTCTimeStamp(1400,12,6));
console.log(jalaliToUTCTimeStamp(1400,12,7));
console.log(jalaliToUTCTimeStamp(1400,12,8));
console.log(jalaliToUTCTimeStamp(1400,12,9));
console.log(jalaliToUTCTimeStamp(1400,12,10));
console.log(jalaliToUTCTimeStamp(1400,12,11));
//==========================================================
```

Comment: How could I use it on this format date : d-m-yy (e.g. 15-12-1400)? (as I edit my question}

Comment: Also how could I change the code to use this on a field entry by specific ID or Class?

Comment: If you want the output to be in a date format (ISO Date Format) then change the code `return +g;` to: `return g;`; i.e. without the plus sign.